# "group_list("g", ["a","b","c"]) returns "g: a, b, c"" I have tried the following, anyone knows how to remove the " , " in the end?

Tags: python

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = ""
  for x in users:
      members = members + x + ", "
  return "{}: ".format(group) + members

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", "")) # Should be "Users:
```

My results are:

1. Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha,
2. Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom,
3. Users:

I want to know how to remove the ' , ' in the end. Thank you!

Comment: `members = ', '.join(users)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want something inserted *between* elements of a list, instead of always before or after, you probably want `.join()`.

```py
def group_list(group, users):
    members = ", ".join(users)
    return "{}: ".format(group) + members
```

Comment: Or just: `return f'{group}: {", ".join(users)}'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can use `.join()`

```
def group_list(group, users):
    return "{}: ".format(group) + ','.join(users)

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) # Should be "Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha"
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"])) # Should be "Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom"
print(group_list("Users", ""))
```